# What is best practice on passing state and callbacks from root component to leaf components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react application with hierarchy.
Forms have sub-forms, which have groups of parameters, which have parameters.
Each parameters have an array of values. The values can be added to the array or removed from the array (table with remove buttons and input field with add button is rendered for each parameter).

At the end I need to generate all possible cross-parameter combinations of values in the arrays in the root component and display each possible combination as a row in the table which sits in root component.

Thus I am holding all state (value arrays of each parameter) in the root element. This is a bit cumbersome, because I need to bubble down the callbacks to add/remove value from the array of values for given parameter.

Also the callback function that I am bubbling down needs to have "this" bound in the root element but parameters are bound in the leaf-components of the component tree.

Imagine for example that I want to remove a value from a array of values of given parameter of given parameter group of given sub-form. I have to bubble down the id of sub-form, id of parameter group and id of the parameter and then call remove function passed down from the root with all these ids.

Is this a correct approach or is there a better way?

Comment: Have you considered Flux/Redux/MobX?

Comment: It really sounds like you're manually doing what Redux does for you.  Take a look at Dan Abramov's tutorials on Redux to see if it might be useful to you: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the old style way, which get cumbersome for large hierarchies.

React also provides [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) to automatically bubble information down, but discourages its use.

Lots of people now use frameworks like [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) to manage the state.